# Where do the webpack output files from the react-hot-loader go?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Let me preface this by saying that everything I have set up works, this is just a question that's nagging me that I would love to get an answer for.  I'm using the react-hot-boilerplate project (https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate).  However, in `webpack.config.js`, this setting is confusing me to no end:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/static/'
},
```

In this config, it looks like the output file should go into the `dist` folder in root of the project.  Even if I manually create the `dist` folder (which I know I shouldn't have to do), no file gets outputted.  Yet everything works totally fine; the app loads and will hot-reload if I change something in the components.  Where is this output file actually going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the heavy lifting for react-hot-boilerplate (in terms of hot reloading files) is done by the webpack-dev-server dependency.

webpack-dev-server in turn uses [webpack-dev-middleware](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html) to handle the serving of the files (from express).

[This bit of documentation about Webpack Dev Server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) should give you a good overview about how the mechanism works:

> Using this config webpack-dev-server will serve the static files in
>   your build folder and watch your source files for changes. When
>   changes are made the bundle will be recompiled. This modified bundle
>   is served from memory at the relative path specified in publicPath
>   (see API). It will not be written to your configured output directory.
>   Where a bundle already exists at the same url path the bundle in
>   memory will take precedence.
>
> For example with the configuration above your bundle will be available
>   at localhost:8080/assets/bundle.js

And this is a good bit from the webpack-dev-middleware docs:

> The webpack-dev-middleware is a small middleware for a connect-based
>   middleware stack. It uses webpack to compile assets in-memory and
>   serve them. When a compilation is running every request to the served
>   webpack assets is blocked until we have a stable bundle.

So, inside the dev server, the files are written to an in memory-file system and then served.  The assets endpoint serves files from the in-memory location as well as creates a web socket connection to push down further changes.